# replace value in x randomly selected columns in pandas row

Tags: python, pandas

How do I replace the value in x randomly selected columns in the last two rows of a pandas df?  I find this for columns but not for rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
import random

x = 4
df.iloc[-2:, random.sample(list(range(df.shape[1])), x)] = 'X'
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33   X  35   X   X  38   X
4  40  41  42  43   X  45   X   X  48   X
```

Used input:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
```